# How to customize Navbar property in Yii2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2-advanced-app

I have navigation header like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
            <span id="searchicon" class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I have problem when I want to convert this code using `yii\bootstrap\NavBar;`:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
           <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
                <span id="searchicon" class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
      </form>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

And this is the code of my `Layout` using `yii\bootstrap\NavBar;`:

```
<?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            'role' => 'navigation',
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
?>
```

I have been read [Navbar Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-navbar.html), but still don't understand. Is there anyone who can teach me to using `Navbar` widget on `Yii2 framework`?.

Comment: did you solve this problem or not yet??

Comment: @MikeRoss not yet. could you teach me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: On what page are you using the Navbar? in Main layout or you want to use it directly in view file? Not that it makes much of a difference but include the code of that page on which you want to use this navbar

Comment: @MikeRoss i want to use navbar in main layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here is the code for that,here i am just placing the `searchbox` from exactly what you posted in question and i am guessing that you know how to `echo` other menu links in navbar

Anyway it goes like this

```
<?php
NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
    'class' => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    'role' => 'navigation',
],
]);

$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['controller url here']],
];

 echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
echo "<form class='navbar-form navbar-right' role='search'>
       <div class='form-group has-feedback'>
            <input id='searchbox' type='text' placeholder='Search' class='form-control'>
            <span id='searchicon' class='fa fa-search form-control-feedback'></span>
        </div>
  </form>";
NavBar::end();
?>
```

Comment: @Shinoda_ happy to help